# FHIR - Repeated patient resource on a single xml message

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are querying a web service to retrieve a list of patients.
Is there a way to encapsulate several  tags in a root element that matches the FHIR standard ?

Or is FHIR dedicated to manage patient one by one ?

Comment: You can search for a set of patients. is that what you want? perhaps you could clarify your language - what do you mean "encapsulate several tags in a root element"?

Comment: Below an example of what I need:
<patient>
  <name> ... </name>
  <birthDate> ... </birthDate>
  <gender> ... </gender>
  ...
</patient>
<patient>
  <name> ... </name>
  <birthDate> ... </birthDate>
  <gender> ... </gender>
  ...
</patient>
...

Is that was you call a set of patient ?
I've searched for "set of patients" on FHIR website but did not find it, do you have a link ?
By encapsulate I mean putting this message in kind of a unique node as <root></root>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to retrieve a list of patients. Here's examples:

- http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient?_id=1,2,example (DSTU 1)
- http://fhir-dev.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient?_id=1,2,example (Candidate DSTU 2)

If you just use those URLs directly, you'll get an HTML view of the underlying format. Use a REST explorer (e.g. Postman) to see the underlying XML, which, for the DSTU 1 case, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title>Search results for resource type Patient</title>
  <id>urn:uuid:fac88057-33e9-4401-86da-c86027d36b</id>
  <link href="http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/" rel="fhir-base" />
  <link href="http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/_search?_format=text/xml+fhir&amp;search-id=ac47863c-3d02-4ac8-9fdd-fcb2467f60&amp;&amp;_id=1%2C2%2Cexample&amp;search-sort=_id" rel="self" />
  <updated>2015-01-08T20:27:45Z</updated>
  <totalResults xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">3</totalResults>
  <entry>
    <title>Patient "1" Version "22"</title>
    <id>http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/1</id>
    <link href="http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/1/_history/22" rel="self" />
    <updated>2014-12-23T17:34:02Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Anonymous (155.230.118.94)</name>
    </author>
    <published>2015-01-08T20:27:45Z</published>
    <content type="text/xml">
      <Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
        <text>
          <status value="generated"/>
          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Everywoman, Eve. SSN:&#xA;            444222222</div>
        </text>
        <identifier>
          <label value="SSN"/>
          <system value="http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn"/>
          <value value="444222222"/>
        </identifier>
        <name>
          <use value="official"/>
          <family value="Everywoman"/>
          <given value="Susan"/>
        </name>
        <telecom>
          <system value="phone"/>
          <value value="555-555-2003"/>
          <use value="work"/>
        </telecom>
        <gender>
          <coding>
            <system value="http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/AdministrativeGender"/>
            <code value="M"/>
          </coding>
        </gender>
        <birthDate value="2002-09-09"/>
        <address>
          <use value="home"/>
          <line value="2222 Home Street"/>
        </address>
        <managingOrganization>
          <reference value="Organization/hl7"/>
        </managingOrganization>
        <active value="true"/>
      </Patient>
    </content>
    <summary type="xhtml">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Everywoman, Eve. SSN:&#xA;            444222222</div>
    </summary>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>Patient "2" Version "2"</title>
    <id>http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/2</id>
    <link href="http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/2/_history/2" rel="self" />
    <updated>2014-11-07T06:17:07Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Anonymous (72.130.166.78)</name>
    </author>
    <published>2015-01-08T20:27:45Z</published>
    <content type="text/xml">
      <Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
        <text>
          <status value="generated"/>
          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Everyman, Adam. SSN:&#xA;            444333333</div>
        </text>
        <identifier>
          <label value="SSN"/>
          <system value="http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn"/>
          <value value="444333333"/>
        </identifier>
        <name>
          <use value="official"/>
          <family value="Everyman"/>
          <given value="Adam"/>
        </name>
        <telecom>
          <system value="phone"/>
          <value value="555-555-2014"/>
          <use value="work"/>
        </telecom>
        <gender>
          <coding>
            <system value="http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/AdministrativeGender"/>
            <code value="M"/>
          </coding>
        </gender>
        <address>
          <use value="home"/>
          <line value="2222 Home Street"/>
        </address>
        <managingOrganization>
          <reference value="Organization/hl7"/>
        </managingOrganization>
        <active value="true"/>
      </Patient>
    </content>
    <summary type="xhtml">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Everyman, Adam. SSN:&#xA;            444333333</div>
    </summary>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>Patient "example" Version "25"</title>
    <id>http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/example</id>
    <link href="http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/example/_history/25" rel="self" />
    <updated>2014-12-02T06:23:30Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Anonymous (1.22.102.13)</name>
    </author>
    <published>2015-01-08T20:27:45Z</published>
    <content type="text/xml">
      <Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
        <text>
          <status value="generated"/>
          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>
              <b>Generated Narrative</b>
            </p><p>
              <b>name</b>: </p>
            <ul>
              <li>Peter Chalmers </li>
              <li>Peter Chalmers </li>
            </ul><p>
              <b>telecom</b>: </p>
            <ul>
              <li>ph: (03) 5555 6473</li>
              <li>ph: -unknown-</li>
              <li>peter.chalmers@healthintersections.com</li>
              <li>ph: (03) 5555 6473</li>
              <li>ph: -unknown-</li>
              <li>peter.chalmers@healthintersections.com</li>
            </ul><p>
              <b>gender</b>: Male <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details : { code "M" := "", given as "Male"})</span>
            </p><p>
              <b>birthDate</b>: 1974-11-25T00:11:00+05:30</p><p>
              <b>deceased</b>: -1</p><p>
              <b>address</b>: </p>
            <ul>
              <li>534 Erewhon St           PleasantVille Alabama 3999 </li>
              <li>534 Erewhon St            PleasantVille Alabama 3999 </li>
            </ul><p>
              <b>maritalStatus</b>: Single <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
            </p><p>
              <b>multipleBirth</b>: 0</p><p>
              <b>communication</b>: </p>
            <ul>
              <li>Spanish <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
              </li>
              <li>English <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
              </li>
              <li>Spanish <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
              </li>
              <li>English <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
              </li>
            </ul><p>
              <b>careProvider</b>: </p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="Practitioner/131">Practitioner/131</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="Practitioner/132">Practitioner/132</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="Practitioner/133">Practitioner/133</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="Practitioner/134">Practitioner/134</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="Practitioner/143">Practitioner/143</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </text>
        <name>
          <family value="Chalmers"/>
          <given value="Peter"/>
        </name>
        <name>
          <family value="Chalmers"/>
          <given value="Peter"/>
        </name>
        <telecom>
          <system value="phone"/>
          <value value="(03) 5555 6473"/>
        </telecom>
        <telecom>
          <system value="phone"/>
        </telecom>
        <telecom>
          <system value="email"/>
          <value value="peter.chalmers@healthintersections.com"/>
        </telecom>
        <telecom>
          <system value="phone"/>
          <value value="(03) 5555 6473"/>
        </telecom>
        <telecom>
          <system value="phone"/>
        </telecom>
        <telecom>
          <system value="email"/>
          <value value="peter.chalmers@healthintersections.com"/>
        </telecom>
        <gender>
          <coding>
            <code value="M"/>
            <display value="Male"/>
          </coding>
          <text value="Male"/>
        </gender>
        <birthDate value="1974-11-25T00:11:00+05:30"/>
        <deceasedBoolean value="true"/>
        <address>
          <line value="534 Erewhon St          "/>
          <city value="PleasantVille"/>
          <state value="Alabama"/>
          <zip value="3999"/>
        </address>
        <address>
          <line value="534 Erewhon St           "/>
          <city value="PleasantVille"/>
          <state value="Alabama"/>
          <zip value="3999"/>
        </address>
        <maritalStatus>
          <text value="Single"/>
        </maritalStatus>
        <multipleBirthBoolean value="false"/>
        <communication>
          <text value="Spanish"/>
        </communication>
        <communication>
          <text value="English"/>
        </communication>
        <communication>
          <text value="Spanish"/>
        </communication>
        <communication>
          <text value="English"/>
        </communication>
        <careProvider>
          <reference value="Practitioner/131"/>
        </careProvider>
        <careProvider>
          <reference value="Practitioner/132"/>
        </careProvider>
        <careProvider>
          <reference value="Practitioner/133"/>
        </careProvider>
        <careProvider>
          <reference value="Practitioner/134"/>
        </careProvider>
        <careProvider>
          <reference value="Practitioner/143"/>
        </careProvider>
      </Patient>
    </content>
    <summary type="xhtml">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>
          <b>Generated Narrative</b>
        </p><p>
          <b>name</b>: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Peter Chalmers </li>
          <li>Peter Chalmers </li>
        </ul><p>
          <b>telecom</b>: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>ph: (03) 5555 6473</li>
          <li>ph: -unknown-</li>
          <li>peter.chalmers@healthintersections.com</li>
          <li>ph: (03) 5555 6473</li>
          <li>ph: -unknown-</li>
          <li>peter.chalmers@healthintersections.com</li>
        </ul><p>
          <b>gender</b>: Male <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details : { code "M" := "", given as "Male"})</span>
        </p><p>
          <b>birthDate</b>: 1974-11-25T00:11:00+05:30</p><p>
          <b>deceased</b>: -1</p><p>
          <b>address</b>: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>534 Erewhon St           PleasantVille Alabama 3999 </li>
          <li>534 Erewhon St            PleasantVille Alabama 3999 </li>
        </ul><p>
          <b>maritalStatus</b>: Single <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
        </p><p>
          <b>multipleBirth</b>: 0</p><p>
          <b>communication</b>: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Spanish <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
          </li>
          <li>English <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
          </li>
          <li>Spanish <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
          </li>
          <li>English <span style="background: LightGoldenRodYellow ">(Details )</span>
          </li>
        </ul><p>
          <b>careProvider</b>: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="Practitioner/131">Practitioner/131</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Practitioner/132">Practitioner/132</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Practitioner/133">Practitioner/133</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Practitioner/134">Practitioner/134</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Practitioner/143">Practitioner/143</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </summary>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It helps a lot ! that's exactly what i was searching for.